# AltBeacon enterRegion never called

Tags: android, altbeacon

I bought the following Beacon([Link](https://www.amazon.de/iBeacon-Bluetooth-Programmierbares-Beacon-AAA-Batterie/dp/B019G0W160/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1479054392&sr=8-1&keywords=c1%20bluetooth%20beacon)).

I went through  this [tutorial](http://www.software7.com/blog/creating-a-beacon-app-for-android-in-less-than-10-minutes-from-scratch/) and ended up like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {

    private BeaconManager beaconManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        Log.d(TAG, "connectedService");
        beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                try {
                    Log.d("beaconTest", "didENTERRegion");
                    beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                try {
                    Log.d("beaconTest", "didEXITRegion");
                    beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {

            }
        });

        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                for (Beacon beacon : beacons){
                    Log.d("beaconTest", "distance: " +
                            beacon.getDistance() + "id: " +
                            beacon.getId1() + "/" +
                            beacon.getId2() + "/" +
                            beacon.getId3());
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }

}
```

My Problem is that the method `didEnterRegion()` is never called and I can't figure out why. The minimal SDK version is set to 18 and I activated Bluetooth on my phone and requested the permission for the App. I can find the beacon with 3rd party apps but not with my code. Can someone tell me what I can do to fix this problem?

Here's my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my debug-output:

```
$ adb shell am start -n "com.test/com.test.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Connecting to com.test
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/ActivityThread: Application com.test is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/art: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1381)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.test-1/lib/arm
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.test, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.test-1/lib/arm
D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
W/BluetoothCrashResolver: Can't read macs from BluetoothCrashResolverState.txt
W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: App has no android.permission.INTERNET permission.  Cannot check for distance model updates
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 166ada0, Ifd751822f5
          Build Date                       : 01/26/16
          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
          Local Branch                     : AU12_SBA
          Remote Branch                    : 
          Remote Branch                    : 
          Reconstruct Branch               : 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/BeaconsEverywhere: connectedService
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Two tips:

- The log never shows `Log.d(TAG, "connectedService");` getting called.  This may just be the log getting cut off prematurely, but if you do not get this callback nothing else will work.  Make sure you are getting it.
- Try moving `beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);` to the `public void didDetermineStateForRegion` callback.  This will start ranging at app startup even if you are already inside the region at app startup.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I have the logMessage 11-15 11:13:30.778 18878-18878/com.test D/BeaconsEverywhere: connectedService. And i moved the startRanging method to didDetermineSateForRegion but nothing changed.

Comment: What do the beacon's identifiers look like in the third party app?  What app are you using?  You might try the Locate app which is based on this same library to see if it detects it. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate

Comment: I found it with the app you posted. The Identifier looks like this: "e2c56db5-dffb-48d2-b060-d0f5a71096e0"

Answer (score -1):

I made the following code so that even beginners can understand. Just copy the code and read comments. Note that the message to be sent is declared as a global variable which you can change just before sending the message. General changes can be done in the Handler function. 
Warning Device requires special permission for API 23 or higher.

The answer about what to include in your manifest.xml for Bluetooth activity includes:

android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"

Try this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
protected static final String TAG = "MonitoringActivity";
TextView textView1;

BeaconUtil beaconUtil = new BeaconUtil();

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Constants.PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "coarse location permission granted");
            } else {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons when in the background.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    }

                });
                builder.show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("This app needs location access");
            builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect beacons.");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        requestPermissions(
                                new String[]{
                                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                                }, Constants.PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    }


    textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textview1);

    beaconUtil.init(this);
    beaconUtil.startScan();
    Util.log("start scan beacon");

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Util.log("stop scan beacon");
            beaconUtil.stopScan();
            Util.log("beaconMajorMinorList:: " + beaconUtil.beaconMajorMinorList);
        }
    }, 10000);
}
}
```

BeaconUtil code :

public class BeaconUtil implements BeaconConsumer {

```
private BeaconManager beaconManager;
private Activity activity;
public final Set<String> beaconMajorMinorList = new HashSet<>();

public void init(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;

    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(activity);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));

}

public void startScan() {
    beaconMajorMinorList.clear();
    beaconManager.bind(this);
}

public void stopScan() {
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}

private void addMonitorNotifier() {

    beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            Util.log("***** ilk görülen beacon *****");
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            Util.log("**** Beacon not view. ****");
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
            Util.log("**** beacon count : " + state);
        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
    }
}

private void addRangeNotifier() {
    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(final Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

            /*
             * Alınan bilgiler: Major, Minor, UID, Distance(Mesafe Uzaklık)
             *
             *  UID = oneBeacon.getId1()
             *  "major:" = oneBeacon.getId2()
             *  "minor:" = oneBeacon.getId3())
             *  proximityUuid:" = oneBeacon.getId1()
             *  "Distance:" = oneBeacon.getDistance() + " meters away."
             * */
            for (Beacon oneBeacon : beacons) {

                Util.log( "The first beacon I see is about " + oneBeacon.getDistance() + " meters away.");
                Util.log("Reading…" + "\n" + "proximityUuid:" + " " + oneBeacon.getId1() + "\n" +
                        "major:" + " " + oneBeacon.getId2() + "\n" +
                        "minor:" + " " + oneBeacon.getId3());

                beaconMajorMinorList.add(oneBeacon.getId2() + "-" + oneBeacon.getId3());
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
    }
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    addRangeNotifier();
    //addMonitorNotifier();
}

@Override
public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return activity;
}

@Override
public void unbindService(ServiceConnection serviceConnection) {
    activity.unbindService(serviceConnection);
}

@Override
public boolean bindService(Intent intent, ServiceConnection serviceConnection, int i) {
    return activity.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, i);
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer